# Rewrite two condition at the same is not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite url in apache web server. there are 2 paths for my web project as the follows:

1- www.test.com/folder1/folder2/index?v1=1&v2=2&v3=3 ==> i want rewrite to www.test.com/index/1/2/3

2- www.test.com/folder3/folder4/index?v1=1&v2=2&v3=3 ==> i want rewrite to www.test.com/index/1/2/3

my rewrite cod as the following:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/folder2
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3/folder4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder3/folder4/$1 [L]
```

Thank you....

Comment: What url do you want to display in the browser, and what url should that rewrite to? One url can only remap to one internal url.

Comment: here url that i want to display : 1- www.test.com/folder1/folder2/index?v1=1&v2=2&v3=3 ==> i want rewrite to www.test.com/index/1/2/3

2- www.test.com/folder3/folder4/index?v1=1&v2=2&v3=3 ==> i want rewrite to www.test.com/index/1/2/3

Comment: Want you URLs like `www.test.com/index/1/2/3` on HTML page? If so, then you need rewriting vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewriterules you have seem to suggest that if the url "www.test.com/index/1/2/3" is entered in the browser url bar, you want to rewrite it internally to either of the urls with a query string. For obvious reasons, that is impossible. One url can (or should) only ever link to one other internal url.

If you want both urls with a query string to load the same page, your site will get penalized in search engines for 'duplicate content'. This is how you do it though.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v1=([^&]*)&v2=([^&]*)&v3=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^(folder1/folder2|folder3/folder4)/index$ index/%1/%2/%3 [L]
```

`%1` through `%3` are replaced by the first, second and third capture group from the previous rewrite condition. In this case, the values from v1, v2 and v3 in the query string.

The documentation can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).